# Convert POJO to JavaFX Property

Tags: java, properties, javafx, javafx-8, pojo

In my project, I have a number of POJOs whose fields are shown in a JavaFX GUI. I currently update the UI using a manual refresh – whenever the POJO changes, I call a `refresh()` method. I would like to attempt using binding to accomplish this instead, which requires using JavaFX properties. Whilst I *can* change the object, its internal fields are other objects, which I cannot change (they are populated using GSON, which AFAIK uses 'normal' Java objects – e.g. String, not StringProperty). Furthermore, the object is read only – it only has getters, not setters.

I believe I can use a ReadOnlyJavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder (yay Java naming?) or a ReadOnlyObjectWrapper to wrap the object as a property. However, the internal fields – which are what I want to bind the Labels to – are not converted to properties. Is there any way of doing such a recursive conversion – convert an entire object which contains normal object fields into a property which contains further properties? Is this even necessary – am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I suspect any solution would have to use reflection.

Comment: I think your refresh is probably the only way.  Here's a related answer I did, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22107105/2855515 .

Comment: I'm currently testing out BeanPathAdapter, as suggested by @Jurgen. It seems to do most of what I want. It will require me to implement setters for the objects, but that isn't too much of an issue (the setters should never be called though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure but have a look at [BeanPathAdapter](http://ugate.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/javafx-programmatic-pojo-expression-bindings-part-iii/)

Its part of JFXtras-Labs, downloadable [jar](http://jfxtras.org/resources/java/jfxtras-labs-samples-8.0-r2-SNAPSHOT-shadow.jar).

Source is [here](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs/tree/8.0/src/main/java/jfxtras/labs/scene/control) on GitHub.

Comment: This looks like it might work. The JavaDoc appears to have some formatting issues, which might make getting started with it a bit harder, but I should figure it out. Thanks!
I'm currently using the ControlsFX library to create dialogs. It looks like I could possibly use JFXtras to replicate this, but their dialogs control looks to be in a bit rougher state to use right now.

Answer (score 2):

How about adapters for the POJOs?

*Example*

```
public class Person{
  private String name;
  private Address addr;

  \\getters, setters...
}
```

*And for the JavaFX GUI*

```
public class FXPerson{
  public FXPerson(Person p){
    this.name = \\build StringProperty
    this.fxaddr = \\build ObjectProperty<FXAddress>
  }

  private StringProperty name;
  private ObjectProperty<FXAddress> fxaddr;
}
```

*Downside:*
For every POJO you will have to write an adapter. And if a POJO changes (e.g. new property etc.) you will need to update the corresponding adapter.

Comment: Something along those lines would work... except for that, using your example, the Address class would have further objects that would need to be accessed, and there would also be even more objects as fields in the Person class (each of which also has objects as fields). In short, the reason I was hoping for some more automated solution was because doing it manually would be a lot of effort for not much gain.

Comment: What about if the POJO has an Enum member?