# JavaFX and Data Binding with JPA entities

Tags: java

As the question says, I would like to know the easiest way to perform Data Binding to regular (non JavaFX) properties of JPA entities.
I was thinking there is probably some way to use the same binding functions if you make your entity class implement some interface for change listeners or something of the sort.

Here is an example of a JPA entity with property changed listeners.

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne()
    private EntryGate entryGate;

    @ManyToOne()
    private ExitGate exitGate;

    @Transient
    private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public Ticket() {
    }

    public Ticket(EntryGate owner) {
        this();
        this.entryGate = owner;
    }

    public void addListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public EntryGate getEntryGate() {
        return entryGate;
    }

    public void setEntryGate(EntryGate entryGate) {
        EntryGate oldGate = this.entryGate;
        this.entryGate = entryGate;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("entryGate", oldGate, this.entryGate);
    }

    public ExitGate getExitGate() {
        return exitGate;
    }

    public void setExitGate(ExitGate exitGate) {
        ExitGate oldGate = this.exitGate;
        this.exitGate = exitGate;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("exitGate", oldGate, this.exitGate);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a JavaFX property binding.
this.idLabel.textProperty().bind(this.ticket.idProperty().asString());

Obviously I can't replace my JPA properties with SimpleXXXProperty... because they are entities participating in object relational mapping.

Comment: _"I was thinking there is probably some way to use the same binding functions if you make your entity class implement some interface for change listeners or something of the sort."_ - Yup, only I would probably suggest implementing the ObjectProperty or extend the SimpleObjectProperty class, so you can use the property functions directly.

Comment: @RyanJ That is how it is done in C#, can you elaborate on how to bind JavaFX properties to POJO properties? I can't find adequate information anywhere.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105162/is-it-possible-to-bind-a-stringproperty-to-a-pojos-string-in-javafx).

Comment: @RyanJ that answer wouldn't work for a situation where you have, for example, a list property whose size you want to bind, since only the list raises property change notifications, and not its size... what would you do in such situations.

Comment: You'd have to bind each property in the list by itself, and you could use the list content change property to determine when, if at all, the list contents change so you can bind accordingly.

Comment: @RyanJ could you explain further, maybe use an example? I can't figure out how to bind a POJO property managed by the list (not myself)...